# NSURLConnection synchronous request from a thread vs asynchronous request

Tags: ios, multithreading, ipad, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

What is the differance between adding a operation which make a synchronous NSURLConnection request in NSOperationQueue ( or synchronous request from a thread ( not main thread)) AND making a asynchronous request from the main thread ?

Both will not block main thread so UI will remain responsive but is there any advantage of using one over other? I know in later method i can track request progress  etc but assume that progress and other HTTP stuff is not important here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asynchronous requests are scheduled on the run loop and setup as a run loop source, triggering the code automatically only when there is data received from the network (as any socket source).

Synchronous requests running on a `NSThread` monopolizes a thread to monitor the incoming data, which is in general quite overkill.

You can always cancel an `NSURLConnection` even if it has been executed asynchronously, using the `cancel` method.

I bet using the new API that allows to send an asynchronous request on an `NSOperationQueue` (`+sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`) uses GCD under the hood and `dispatch_source_create`, or something similar, so that it behave the same way as when an `NSURLConnection` is scheduled on the run loop, avoiding using an additional thread (watch the WWDC'12 videos that explains why threads are evil and their usage should be minimized), the difference only being that allows you to use a block to be informed upon completion instead of using the delegate mechanism.

Some years ago I created a class that embedded `NSURLConnection` asynchronous calls and delegate management into a nice block API (see [OHURLLoader](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHURLLoader) on my github) that makes it easier to use (feel free to take a look). I bet the new API that uses `NSOperationQueue`s uses the same principle, still doing asynchronous requests on the runloop but allowing you to use blocks instead of having to implement a delegate.

Answer (score 5):

They are very similar. The biggest problem with synchronous requests is that they can't easily be cancelled. Depending on your application, that could be a problem. Imagine you are downloading a big document and the user moves to another screen so you no longer need that information. In our case, I actually chose doing asynchronous NSURLConnections on a secondary NSThread, which may be overkill for some apps. It is more complicated, but it gives us the ability to both cancel requests and to decode the JSON/XML/image data on secondary threads so they don't impact main thread user interactivity.

Answer (score 2):

The historical position was that there's an advantage in power consumption, and therefore battery life, in asynchronous requests — presumably including both the older delegate approach and the new block-based approach.

Comment: That makes sense. What *is* the new block-based approach, specifically please?  Not looking for code, just what to ask Google for so I can grok some docs.

Comment: @Madbreaks it is `NSURLConnection +sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`.